# Meta analysis and Forest Plot help

Tags: correlation, meta-analysis

I am trying to do a meta analysis in RStudio (I have very little knowledge here). and I used a function to define m<-meta::metacor and then listed the correlations. it produced what looks to be a decent output. but when I go to try to make that into a forest plot, using meta::forest(m, layout...etc) the output only says error object "m" not found. I have very little experience with R and RStudio so I figured it might be useful to ask someone who has done this more than one time, like myself.

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. Please try to make the question clearer in terms of what you are trying to do and at which point you fail. Consider explaining what kind of meta analysis you are trying to do and by which means. If you think you are failing purely on programming terms, please add the respective tag and change the question title to include something like "Trouble with R".

Comment: This looks like a programming issue which is off-topic on this list. You might want to ry the mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis in R  https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// but you will need to show all the code and not just the error message.  Note also that RStudio is just an interface, what you are usin to do the work is R.